How to get derivation of a function with respect to another function?
I often have this need: I have some functions that have the same variable and have inclusion relationships, like this.
f[t_] := t^2 + 1
g[t_] := Exp[-I  Sin[f[t]]]

Sometimes I need to take the derivative of one function with respect to another, but Mathematica cannot run these codes correctly.
h[t_] := D[g[t], f[t]]
h[t]
h[1]

I also tried Block, Holdform, or rewrite :=(SetDelayed) into the # & form(Function) but it doesn't work. So how can I get the correct result?
Remember that these functions f[t]andg[t] have other uses themselves, and I don't want to make them unusable in the solution.
I hope that the input h[t] can output the result in symbolic form, and h[1] can output the result in digital form. I don't know if this can be done.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please use search and look through the questions on this site; this has been asked many times. For example, using Google.

You could use chainD from this answer, e.g., f[t_] := t^2+1; chainD[Exp[-I  Sin[f[t]]], f[t]]

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[t_] := t^2 + 1
g[t_] := Exp[-I   Sin[f[t]]]

repl = {Reduce[u == f[t], t] // ToRules}

(* {{t -> -Sqrt[-1 + u]}, {t -> Sqrt[-1 + u]}} *)

d1 = (D[g[t] /. repl, u]) /. u -> f[t]

(* {-I E^(-I Sin[1 + t^2]) Cos[1 + t^2], -I E^(-I Sin[1 + t^2]) Cos[1 + t^2]} *)

SameQ @@ d1

(* True *)

Alternatively, using ImplicitD (new in v13.1)
d2 = ImplicitD[g[t], y == f[t], t, y]

(* -I E^(-I Sin[1 + t^2]) Cos[1 + t^2] *)

d1[[1]] === d2

(* True *)


f[t_] := x^2 + 1 is wrong. You need f[t_] := t^2 + 1 then you can use
$$
\frac{dg\left(  t\right)  }{df\left(  t\right)  }=\frac{\frac{dg\left(
t\right)  }{dt}}{\frac{df\left(  t\right)  }{dt}}=\frac{g^{\prime}\left(
t\right)  }{f^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  }%
$$
In Mathematica
f[t_] := t^2 + 1
g[t_] := Exp[-I   Sin[f[t]]]
D[g[t], t]/D[f[t], t]



Since g is defined in terms of f, this also works. `In[47]:= D[Exp[-I*Sin[y]], y] /. y -> f[t]
Out[47]= -I E^(-I Sin[1 + t^2]) Cos[1 + t^2]`
